# Access to previous row in Kettle

Tags: etl, kettle

In Pentaho ETL Kettle i would like to acces previous row in one step. 
Let's declare data flow as myMat:

myMat:

```
      col0  col1
row0: 15    a
row1: 10    b
row2: 24    hi
row3: 11    bye
```

I would like to use this calculation:

```
newNumber= myMat[i][0] + myMat[i-1][0]
```

Do you know any way to do it in Kettle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do this kind of thing with the `Analytic Query` step. You'll need a grouping field in your data set though. If you want to process the entire set as a single group, put an `Add Constants` step before the Analytic Query step that inserts, say a just a 1, and group by that.

Either way, if you want to use it in a calculation, you'll have to deal with NULL. LAG 1 of the first row of your group will always be NULL. If you just want to map that to a 0, you do that with an `If field values is null` step. Here is what it might look like:

[image: Sum of previous row]

However, G Gordon is correct. You should consider if this really makes sense based on the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Thank you. How do you then access the previous value in calculator?

Comment: The analytic query puts the value of the previous row (lag 1) into a new column in the current row.

Comment: Brian.D.Myers, I used your advice. It returned values as expected. However I didn't use Add constants step and grouping in Analytic Query step. In Analytic query I just defined Analytic functions as:
LAG "N" rows BACKWARD and N=1, N=2, N=3 and it worked fine.
Thank you

Comment: Thanks. The trick with using an Add Constants is useful for some of the other steps that deal with aggregates. Apparently Analytic Query doesn't need it, but others seem to, so I always use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this sort of thing in a custom Java or JavaScript step by storing state between each row you process. However...

The order of the stream is not guaranteed. Further, you may process multiple rows in parallel at the same time. So, as you can imagine, this kind of calculation can be problematic. What is it that you are trying to achieve? There is almost certainly a better way.

Comment: I was just told to analyze possibilities to query previoust and forwarding values in stream. I see it is problematic to get eg second-previous value. In my example almost 10000 rows the order of values in stream is the same as on the input. Do you think the stream order can vary in case of more data?

Comment: I'm not aware of the size of the stream changing the likelihood that the stream will be processed in some other order than the "natural" one.